# Azure DevOps REST API returning string in powershell ConvertTo-Json not working

Tags: json, azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to call the following Azure DevOps API endpoint.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-item-types/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#workitemtype

This is supposed to return an object with the following structure:

```
{
  "count": 42,
  "value" : [
    { "name": "Bug"...other props },
  ] 
}
```

I want to be able to run a Powershell where on this...i.e.

```
return $resp | where {$_.value.name -eq "Bug" }
```

However, all JSON dot operations have been useless. I checked the data type being returned from my `Invoke-RestMethod`, and my Powershell says it's returning a String *despite* the fact I've added `ContentType` of `application/json` and additionally attempted to use the pipe `ConvertTo-Json` operator.

```
    PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $wiTypesResp = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $wiTypesUri -Headers $header -ContentType application/json | ConvertTo-Json
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $wiTypesResp.GetType().Name
    String
```

Where am I going wrong here and how do I get this into proper JSON? Looking at the result in the Powershell log, there are no "" before the response - and checking the data in Postman also seems like the data is not a string.

If I do `$wiTypesResp[0]` what returns is "{"

Additionally, attempting to pull the "value" object out so far has been fruitless.

$wiTypesResp.value

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $val = $wiTypesResp | where { $_ -eq "value" }

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $val
```

Get-Member returns:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $resp | Get-Member


   TypeName: System.String

Name             MemberType            Definition                                                                                                                                    
----             ----------            ----------                                                                                                                                    
Clone            Method                System.Object Clone(), System.Object ICloneable.Clone()                                                                                       
CompareTo        Method                int CompareTo(System.Object value), int CompareTo(string strB), int IComparable.CompareTo(System.Object obj), int IComparable[string].Compa...
Contains         Method                bool Contains(string value)                                                                                                                   
CopyTo           Method                void CopyTo(int sourceIndex, char[] destination, int destinationIndex, int count)                                                             
EndsWith         Method                bool EndsWith(string value), bool EndsWith(string value, System.StringComparison comparisonType), bool EndsWith(string value, bool ignoreCa...
Equals           Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj), bool Equals(string value), bool Equals(string value, System.StringComparison comparisonType), bool IEquatab...
GetEnumerator    Method                System.CharEnumerator GetEnumerator(), System.Collections.IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator(), System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator[c...
GetHashCode      Method                int GetHashCode()                                                                                                                             
GetType          Method                type GetType()                                                                                                                                
GetTypeCode      Method                System.TypeCode GetTypeCode(), System.TypeCode IConvertible.GetTypeCode()                                                                     
IndexOf          Method                int IndexOf(char value), int IndexOf(char value, int startIndex), int IndexOf(string value), int IndexOf(string value, int startIndex), int...
IndexOfAny       Method                int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf), int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex), int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex, int count)           
Insert           Method                string Insert(int startIndex, string value)                                                                                                   
IsNormalized     Method                bool IsNormalized(), bool IsNormalized(System.Text.NormalizationForm normalizationForm)                                                       
LastIndexOf      Method                int LastIndexOf(char value), int LastIndexOf(char value, int startIndex), int LastIndexOf(string value), int LastIndexOf(string value, int ...
LastIndexOfAny   Method                int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf), int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex), int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex, int co...
Normalize        Method                string Normalize(), string Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm normalizationForm)                                                         
PadLeft          Method                string PadLeft(int totalWidth), string PadLeft(int totalWidth, char paddingChar)                                                              
PadRight         Method                string PadRight(int totalWidth), string PadRight(int totalWidth, char paddingChar)                                                            
Remove           Method                string Remove(int startIndex, int count), string Remove(int startIndex)                                                                       
Replace          Method                string Replace(char oldChar, char newChar), string Replace(string oldValue, string newValue)                                                  
Split            Method                string[] Split(Params char[] separator), string[] Split(char[] separator, int count), string[] Split(char[] separator, System.StringSplitOp...
StartsWith       Method                bool StartsWith(string value), bool StartsWith(string value, System.StringComparison comparisonType), bool StartsWith(string value, bool ig...
Substring        Method                string Substring(int startIndex), string Substring(int startIndex, int length)                                                                
ToBoolean        Method                bool IConvertible.ToBoolean(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                  
ToByte           Method                byte IConvertible.ToByte(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                     
ToChar           Method                char IConvertible.ToChar(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                     
ToCharArray      Method                char[] ToCharArray(), char[] ToCharArray(int startIndex, int length)                                                                          
ToDateTime       Method                datetime IConvertible.ToDateTime(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                             
ToDecimal        Method                decimal IConvertible.ToDecimal(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                               
ToDouble         Method                double IConvertible.ToDouble(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                 
ToInt16          Method                int16 IConvertible.ToInt16(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                   
ToInt32          Method                int IConvertible.ToInt32(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                     
ToInt64          Method                long IConvertible.ToInt64(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                    
ToLower          Method                string ToLower(), string ToLower(cultureinfo culture)                                                                                         
ToLowerInvariant Method                string ToLowerInvariant()                                                                                                                     
ToSByte          Method                sbyte IConvertible.ToSByte(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                   
ToSingle         Method                float IConvertible.ToSingle(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                  
ToString         Method                string ToString(), string ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider), string IConvertible.ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider)            
ToType           Method                System.Object IConvertible.ToType(type conversionType, System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                       
ToUInt16         Method                uint16 IConvertible.ToUInt16(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                 
ToUInt32         Method                uint32 IConvertible.ToUInt32(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                 
ToUInt64         Method                uint64 IConvertible.ToUInt64(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                 
ToUpper          Method                string ToUpper(), string ToUpper(cultureinfo culture)                                                                                         
ToUpperInvariant Method                string ToUpperInvariant()                                                                                                                     
Trim             Method                string Trim(Params char[] trimChars), string Trim()                                                                                           
TrimEnd          Method                string TrimEnd(Params char[] trimChars)                                                                                                       
TrimStart        Method                string TrimStart(Params char[] trimChars)                                                                                                     
Chars            ParameterizedProperty char Chars(int index) {get;}                                                                                                                  
Length           Property              int Length {get;}
```

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod` automatically converts the json response for you. Use `Invoke-WebRequest` if you want to raw response. The fact that `ConvertTo-Json` outputs a string is _not_ a bug (what other data type would you use to store a raw json string?)

Comment: No, I want JSON, but if I do $wiTypesResp.value...nothing gets outputted.

Comment: Yeah, but JSON is a _textual representation of object data_ - so it's stored in/as a string. If you want to be able to interact with the represented object using PowerShell's regular syntax then you _don't_ want JSON (and don't need to change anything other than removing `ConvertTo-Json`)

Comment: Do you mean ```return $resp.value | where { $_.name -eq "Bug" }```? Note that ```value``` is an array so you're comparing *all* the items's "name"s as a single object using something called Member Enumeration, rather than each individual item one at a time. Either way is valid depending on what you actually want, but they have different meanings...

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I had the same issue before I added ConvertTo-Json. I was unable to use standard dot notation to access the properties of the response.

Comment: @mclayton doesn't work. Returns nothing. PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $obj = $resp.value | where { $_.name -eq "Bug" }

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $obj

Comment: ok, but that might be a "better" nothing :-)

Comment: You _really_ need to remove `ConvertTo-Json` for what @mclayton suggested to work

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen did it.C:\WINDOWS\system32> $resp = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $wiTypesUri -Headers $header -ContentType application/json

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $obj = $resp.value | where { $_.name -eq "Bug" }

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $obj

Comment: What does `$resp |Get-Member` show? Do you see the `value` member?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen. Nope. I updated post to show output of Get-Member since it's so large.

Comment: And if I just log $resp, I can see "Bug" right there on the first object in the value object. PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $resp
{"count":15,"value":[{"name":"Bug","referenceName":"Bug",

Comment: Isn't this all just a matter of using `Convert-ToJson` when you really needed to use `ConvertFrom-Json`?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician. I've tried that as well. Both in the Invoke-RestMethod call and after it. It throws an exception. $wiTypesResp = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $wiTypesUri -Headers $header

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $ps = $wiTypesResp | ConvertFrom-Json
ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is not valid. Change the value of the "name" argument and run the 
operation again.

Comment: Interesting, I just tried it myself and get the same error. That *should* work, but it seems that the JSON that is returned is malformed. For that matter, the sample JSON they give for their response gives the same error.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician here and I thought I've been going crazy as I don't usually have this much issues with calling APIs.

Answer (score 0):

After running into the same issue I split down the sample JSON into chunks that would pass `ConvertFrom-Json` until I had a small bit that wouldn't and saw:

```
    "": [
      {
        "to": "New",
        "actions": null
      }
    ]
```

So I searched my own results for `"":` with:

```
$Results -match '"":.*?[,\]}]'
$Matches

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                
0                              "":[{"to":"To Do",
```

...and sure enough I have a nameless field as well. Once I put a name in there I was able to convert the whole thing from JSON into objects that PowerShell can work with.

```
$URI='https://{Org}.visualstudio.com/{Project}/_apis/wit/workitemtypes?api-version=7.1-preview.2'
$Results=Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $URI -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $header
$objResults = $Results -replace '"":', '"TempText":' | ConvertFrom-Json
```

At that point `$objResults` was a functional object that I could iterate through.